# html content specific css tag

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
<tr><th colspan="7" class="month">January 2017</th></tr>
<tr><th class="mon">Mon</th><th class="tue">Tue</th><th class="wed">Wed</th><th class="thu">Thu</th><th class="fri">Fri</th><th class="sat">Sat</th><th class="sun">Sun</th></tr>
<tr><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="sun">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">2</td><td class="tue">3</td><td class="wed">4</td><td class="thu">5</td><td class="fri">6</td><td class="sat">7</td><td class="sun">8</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">9</td><td class="tue">10</td><td class="wed">11</td><td class="thu">12</td><td class="fri">13</td><td class="sat">14</td><td class="sun">15</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">16</td><td class="tue">17</td><td class="wed">18</td><td class="thu">19</td><td class="fri">20</td><td class="sat">21</td><td class="sun">22</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">23</td><td class="tue">24</td><td class="wed">25</td><td class="thu">26</td><td class="fri">27</td><td class="sat">28</td><td class="sun">29</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">30</td><td class="tue">31</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.sat{
    color: red;
}
.sun{
    color: red;
}
"1" {
    color: blue;
}
```

Currently i am having problems as i need to specifically find the number 1 in my html code and and change that via the css to red without making any of the others red and without editing the html file as the html file will constantly be updated and reset via my python script.

Comment: td class="sun one">1</td>  and "1" {
    color: blue;
} seriously? give the style as  .one{
    color: blue;
}

Comment: wrong code new code uploaded soz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"1" { color: blue; }` is not valid CSS. CSS selectors can't start with numbers for one, and secondly, they are never enclosed in quotation marks.

As the other answers have mentioned, you can fix this by giving your element a class "one" and adjusting the CSS accordingly. I'm not going to post the CSS here as there are 3 answers here that already show that.

Your question, however, leads me to believe that this isn't necessarily an option that is available to you. The problem is that this can be achieved, but not by CSS alone. You will have to use a script to target these elements. For the sake of a complete answer, you could use the below jQuery script to achieve this:

```
<script>
    $('td').each(function(){ //loop through each td
        if($(this).html() == '1') { //if the content of the td is exactly "1" (without quotes)
            $(this).css({'color':'blue'}); //change the CSS rule to have color:blue;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks i've been looking for around for around an hour and only found things on JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.one {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" class="month">January 2017</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="mon">Mon</th>
    <th class="tue">Tue</th>
    <th class="wed">Wed</th>
    <th class="thu">Thu</th>
    <th class="fri">Fri</th>
    <th class="sat">Sat</th>
    <th class="sun">Sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="sun one">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mon">2</td>
    <td class="tue">3</td>
    <td class="wed">4</td>
    <td class="thu">5</td>
    <td class="fri">6</td>
    <td class="sat">7</td>
    <td class="sun">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mon">9</td>
    <td class="tue">10</td>
    <td class="wed">11</td>
    <td class="thu">12</td>
    <td class="fri">13</td>
    <td class="sat">14</td>
    <td class="sun">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mon">16</td>
    <td class="tue">17</td>
    <td class="wed">18</td>
    <td class="thu">19</td>
    <td class="fri">20</td>
    <td class="sat">21</td>
    <td class="sun">22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mon">23</td>
    <td class="tue">24</td>
    <td class="wed">25</td>
    <td class="thu">26</td>
    <td class="fri">27</td>
    <td class="sat">28</td>
    <td class="sun">29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="mon">30</td>
    <td class="tue">31</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already added a class `.one` to your HTML so what you need to do is just add:

```
.one{color:blue;}
```

in your CSS

EDIT: 
What I've just said have sense if `.one` is used only on the element that contain "1" but seeing your HTML it looks so

Answer (score 0):

```css
.one{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:contains(1)").css("color", "red");
});
</script>!-->
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
<tr><th colspan="7" class="month">January 2017</th></tr>
<tr><th class="mon">Mon</th><th class="tue">Tue</th><th class="wed">Wed</th><th class="thu">Thu</th><th class="fri">Fri</th><th class="sat">Sat</th><th class="sun">Sun</th></tr>
<tr><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="sun one">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">2</td><td class="tue">3</td><td class="wed">4</td><td class="thu">5</td><td class="fri">6</td><td class="sat">7</td><td class="sun">8</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">9</td><td class="tue">10</td><td class="wed">11</td><td class="thu">12</td><td class="fri">13</td><td class="sat">14</td><td class="sun">15</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">16</td><td class="tue">17</td><td class="wed">18</td><td class="thu">19</td><td class="fri">20</td><td class="sat">21</td><td class="sun">22</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">23</td><td class="tue">24</td><td class="wed">25</td><td class="thu">26</td><td class="fri">27</td><td class="sat">28</td><td class="sun">29</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mon">30</td><td class="tue">31</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td><td class="noday">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

It will highlight the td which has 1 in it.

Comment: have done it was just the problem with the one class in the html it shouldnt bee there as it is not in the generated version of the code